# Injecting a mount into a disjoint mount namespace behind a private mount propagation?

Tags: linux, docker, containerd, linux-namespaces

As part of some work I'm doing on container diagnostics tooling for Linux container systems like docker and containerd/runc, I've been looking for a way to inject or bind a mount from one mount namespace into another disjoint mount namespace.

### Problem statement

Consider the following scenario

```
hostdir                                   nsdir
-------                                   -----
/                                         /         [mountns 1, pidns 1, ]
  /var/containers/container1-root         /         [mountns 2, pidns 2, propagation=private]
    [not visible]                         /c1volume [mountns 2, pidns 2]
  /var/containers/container2-root         /         [mountns 3, pidns 1, propagation=private] privileged]
```

`container1` is a regular container. It has a volume mounted  on `c1volume`. Due to mount propagation rules, the host cannot see `c1volume`, as it's mounted after the new mount namespace is entered.

`container2` is run with the pid namespace of the host, so it can "see" out of the container to interact with the host. It's privileged, and can use `nsenter` to container-break into the host mount namespace too.

**The goal is to make the filesystem at /var/container/container2-root visible to processes running in container1's namespace, mount namespace 2**, e.g. so that processes in `container1` can access additional injected tools or utilities not usually included in their container image, and they see the pid numbers for pidns 2 (container1).

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this.

Mount propagation rules mean that bind-mounting from the host's mount namespace does not make the bind mount visible to processes in `container1`'s mount namespace:

```
mkdir /var/containers/container1-root/container2
mount -o bind /var/containers/container2-root /var/containers/container1-root/container2
```

Changing the mount propagation of `/var/containers/container1-root` appears to have no effect on this.

I could create a new mount and process namespace that can see `/var/containers/container1-root` as `/` and has a bind mount visible for `/var/containers/container2-root`, but it won't see any of the processes in the original container1 pid namespace, and it won't see the mount of `/c1volume`.

I've tried a great many variations of tricks with `pivot_root`, `unshare`, `nsenter`, `mount -o bind` etc, as yet to no avail.

The co-operation of the leader process (pid 1) of `container1` is not available; this is an external injection from the container tooling layer.

### Demo setup

Here's a setup recipe to create a demo environment with handmade containerization using low-level Linux primitives so you can see what's going on.

```
# create "container images" (static)
mkdir images
cd images
mkdir -p container1-root/{bin,proc,sys,dev,etc} 
curl -sSLf -o container1-root/bin/busybox busybox https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.35.0-x86_64-linux-musl/busybox
chmod +x container1-root/bin/busybox
for cmd in ls mount sh ; do ln -s busybox container1-root/bin/$cmd; done
cat > container1-root/enter <<'__END__'
#!/bin/sh
mount -t sysfs none /sys
exec /bin/busybox sh -i
__END__
chmod +x container1-root/enter
cp -aR container1-root container2-root
touch container1-root/container1
touch container2-root/container2
mkdir container1-root/c1volume
cd ..

# Create a volume for c1
mkdir -p volumes/c1volume
touch volumes/c1volume/i-see-c1volume

# create the container runtime dirs
for c in container1-root container2-root; do
mkdir -p {containers,workdirs,scratch}/$c
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=$PWD/images/$c,upperdir=$PWD/scratch/$c,workdir=$PWD/workdirs/$c $PWD/containers/$c
mount --make-rprivate $PWD/containers/$c
done

# [Terminal session 1: container1]
# Launch container1, with mounted volume not visible to the host and new pid namespace.
unshare -m 
mount -o bind volumes/c1volume containers/container1-root/c1volume
ls containers/container1-root/c1volume/
unshare -p -m --mount-proc --fork --propagation private --wd=containers/container1-root --root=containers/container1-root /enter
PS1='container1 # '
ls /c1volume
echo $$

# [Terminal session 2: container2]
# This container shares the host pid namespace, but not mount namespace, and does not
# have a mounted volume.
unshare -m
unshare -m --mount-proc --fork --propagation private --wd=containers/container2-root --root=containers/container2-root /enter
PS1='container2 # '
```

### Demo

Now, from the host, you will see

```
host # findmnt | egrep 'c1volume|container[12]'
├─/root/containers/container1-root                  overlay                                        overlay         rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root/images/container1-root,upperdir=/root/scratch/container1-root,workdir=/root/workdirs/container1-root
└─/root/containers/container2-root                  overlay                                        overlay         rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root/images/container2-root,upperdir=/root/scratch/container2-root,workdir=/root/workdirs/container2-root
```

no c1volume is visible, and

```
host # ls /root/containers/container1-root/c1volume/
host #
```

its bind-mounted contents are not visible.

A process in container2 can container-break and then `nsenter` container 2:

```
container2 # /bin/busybox nsenter -t 1 -m -p /bin/bash -w /root
host # nsenter -t "$(lsof -t containers/container1-root)" --all -w -r /bin/sh
# ls /c1volume
i-see-c1volume
```

but has no way to access `container2-root` from there.

It's possible to `mount -o bind` into `/proc/$(lsof -t containers/container1-root)/root/`, but mount propagation means this won't be seen from the existing processes in `container1-root`. And if `nsenter` or `unshare` are used to first enter the mount namespace for container1, the container2-root file system is no longer visible so it cannot be bind-mounted.

Answer (score 3):

So of course I work it out after finally writing this up. At least for my demo env, I have to compare to a real containerd to see.

The trick is that `nsenter` without any `--root` or `--wd` will remain in the host rootdir and workdir, but enter the guest mount namespace. It is *not necessary to enter the guest (container1) pid namespace as well*.

```
host # c1leader="$(lsof -t containers/container1-root)"
host # nsenter -t $c1leader -m
host # findmnt -o +PROPAGATION | egrep 'container[12]|c1volume'
├─/root/containers/container1-root                  overlay                                           overlay         rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root/images/container1-root,upperdir=/root/scratch/container1-root,workdir=/root/workdirs/container1-root private
│ ├─/root/containers/container1-root/c1volume       /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root[/root/volumes/c1volume] ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro                                                                                                   private
│ ├─/root/containers/container1-root/proc           proc                                              proc            rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                                                                 private
│ │ └─/root/containers/container1-root/proc         none                                              proc            rw,relatime                                                                                                                     private
│ └─/root/containers/container1-root/sys            none                                              sysfs           rw,relatime                                                                                                                     private
└─/root/containers/container2-root                  overlay                                           overlay         rw,relatime,lowerdir=/root/images/container2-root,upperdir=/root/scratch/container2-root,workdir=/root/workdirs/container2-root private
host # mkdir /root/containers/container1-root/container2-root
host # mount -o bind,ro /root/containers/container2-root /root/containers/container1-root/container2-root
```

now in `container1`'s session:

```
container1 # ls /
bin              c1volume         container1       container2-root  dev              enter            etc              foo              proc             sys
container1 # ls /c1volume/
i-see-c1volume
container1 # ls container2-root/
bin         container2  dev         enter       etc         proc        sys
container1 # busybox ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 0         0:00 /bin/busybox sh -i
   24 0         0:00 busybox ps
```